After using the example code on the TidierPlots.jl github website I got an error
The code I used
Github website: https://tidierorg.github.io/TidierPlots.jl/latest/
    using TidierPlots
    using DataFrames
    using PalmerPenguins

    penguins = dropmissing(DataFrame(PalmerPenguins.load()))

    @ggplot(data = penguins) + 
        @geom_bar(aes(x = species)) +
        @labs(x = "Species")


The error I got

ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: `@ggplot` not defined in expression
starting at Untitled-1:7

I already tried reinstalling the package and using web compiler. I honestly don't know where the problem lies.

I advise you to change the title of your post so that it is more understandable.

Can you point to the exact URL containing the sample code you are copying? Nowhere in the most recent documentation can I find the use of ggplot as a macro rather than a function.

Link to the website: https://tidierorg.github.io/TidierPlots.jl/latest/

The documentation is out of date. Try the examples at https://tidierorg.github.io/TidierPlots.jl/latest/examples/generated/UserGuide/docs_bridge/.
